# Setting speed of cycle to a carousel on hovering

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Hover on a carousel is what I have made with the code below, but I'm trying to set the speed of the cycling after the user has hovered over the carousel.

I have tried using interval and that didn't work either.

```
<script>
  $('.carousel').hover(function() {
  $(this).carousel('cycle'),
         speed: 600;

  })

  .mouseleave(function() {
     $(this).carousel('pause');
   }); 

</script>
```

Comment: so is your intention that the carousel automatically cycles on hover? and is paused when not hovered?

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="carousel slide" id="theCarousel" data-interval="3000">
```

use the data-interval attribute on the carousel.
Here is an example i found
[Carousel Image slider](http://www.tapankumar.in/2014/01/carousel-image-slider-in-twiter-bootstrap.html)